# Issue in handling excel in Selenium with Apache poi

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

```
My code:

package read_write;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.google.common.base.Function;


public class Readexcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File src = new File("D:\\J\\clients_pw.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheet("MAS_details");
    String data1 = sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(data1);
}

}
```

I am facing following error while trying to execute this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)     at
>   org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
>     at read_write.Readexcel.main(Readexcel.java:19)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

I am not sure if i have added all jars. i have added all apache poi jars and google collect

Comment: You have clearly not added all the jars, hence the exception! What happens if you download the Apache POI binary package, and add all the jars it ships with?  See also http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components

Comment: @Gagravarr: The missing `commons-compress-1.18.jar`, which `poi-ooxml` needs in version `4.0.0`, neither is mentioned in your linked component map nor is it shipped with the `poi-bin-4.0.0-20180907.zip`.

Comment: @AxelRichter: yay..its working after adding commons-compress-1.18.jar. 
It gave filenot found: inputstream error when i installed 1.5 version. But with 1.18 its working fine. Thanks.
Thanks Gagravarr

Comment: raised https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62742 for the missing commons-compress jar in poi bin zip - this is why I like using build tools that support maven and/or ivy repos (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.0.0/jar shows that the commons-compress dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much even i had the same issue. It resolved after adding Compress jar